# Flight search with NOT (region) as destination and/or origin?

Tags: international-travel, planning, flight-search-engines

Say you are willing to go almost anywhere, but you MUST be out of Schengen by a particular date. Or you have a warrant for your arrest in a particular country.

Several search engines allow "anywhere" or some entire country as destination, but is there one that allows you to specify where you WON'T go?

And/or to specify places you cannot start **from**.

Filtering or scrolling through the results isn't always practical when the first umpteen dozen pages are the ones that aren't useful.  (Like Bermuda being part of UK or Guam being part of USA.)

Azuon was a good choice for a while, but it has been broken for at least two years.  ("There are no flights for your criteria"—when the criteria is from North America to Taiwan or South Korea during the months of May and June!)

Comment: Or go from UK to USA, but NOT start in that part of UK called Bermuda!  :-)

Comment: I like the use-case with warrant. It's evident that you are non-professional criminal, as you don't know such nuts and bolts :)

Comment: The closest I know of is a site that allows you to search using destination and date, and it then shows all flights, but allows filtering afterwards, allows you to search by region as well as see where your visa free travel is by stating your nationality. It's also map based so you can just simply ignore the sections you know you can't go to: https://greatescape.co (I have no affiliation with this site, I just love it a lot)

Comment: @Suncatcher: well, as far as I know, I'm wanted everywhere—as a tourist.

Comment: @Uciebila, I clarified the post a bit.  GreatEscape looks nice, but it apparently makes me put in a single airpot for origin.  Usually, I want to go from a _region_ or _country_ to another.  I gave leaving Schengen as an example.  Spain is part of Schengen, and the Canaries are part of Spain, but I wouldn't be able to bicycle to an airport in the Canary Islands!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot of Google Flights]

Google Flights allows one to search for flights on a map. You could enter "Spain" or "Europe" as destinations.

Having the results on a map allow for easy exclusion simply by only looking at areas of interest.

*While not a perfect answer this is easier than looking at a plain list of flights to mixed locations.*

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a site that does what you want but using Kayak Explore (https://www.kayak.com/explore/) you can see a map with the prices displayed for a given date and can help you get out of the region for the lowest price

Answer (score -1):

I find that this could fall under the category of "I want all destinations with flags that contain blue but don't have stripes".

Finding a public service that can do this is hard but that doesn't stop you from developing an app of your own that can do this.

There are *a lot* of Flight API's available and combining these with some geographic data (idk what you mean by "region") should be rather easy. This however requires some programming skills.

Comment: I retired in 2014.  Hundreds of thousands of lines of code before that, a couple of dozen since.  :-). Seriously, I contacted OAG about a license to their database but got no response.  I am quite certain I could have written SQL to do what I wanted.  But now, I am no longer wandering, so …